# how are strings saved in an sqlite3 database file?

Tags: sqlite, command-line

I have a table  with 2 columns in TEXT format and one in Double format.

When i Export the data as csv file there are no quotes"" around strings.

```
I expected : 
"150120","22:30",20.7

I got:
150120,22:30,20.7
```

Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 1):

In CSV files, all values are strings.

The `sqlite3` tool quotes values only when necessary, i.e., when they contain spaces, commas, or quotes.